# angular services uses within a function in a component

Tags: angular

```
export class ChartTypeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router, private tService: TypeService) { }
    ngOnInit() { }

    vc_generate() {
        this.tService.template_type$.subscribe((selectedTemplate) => {
            console.log(selectedTemplate);
        });
    }

}
```

i need to call the service method from functions in the component...
When i call the service inside from the ngOnInit() it works fine,,but not works when used inside the function
is any wrong?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific please? Do you mean it doesn't compile? It throws an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: When you are not calling the function from ngOnInit(), in that case from where you are calling that function?

Comment: it doesn't work means ,when calling the function vc_generate(),need to print the selectTemplate value in console..                                                                 when i call the service from ngOnInit() it prints the values in console

Comment: The function will not automatically call.You have to call vc_generate function from a click or something, if not from ngOnInit()

Comment: yes,,i know that.. i am calling the function when an button is clicked       <button id="btn_vchart" class="vchart" (click)="vc_generate()">Create</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem by changing Subject to BehaviorSubject in Service..so a subject does not hold values, it just passes them through. if you change from Subject to BehaviorSubject, then it would hold the value you sent it

now the value is printed in the console.